# Problem with my iPhone 6 calendar

Tags: iphone, calendar

After doing the last iOS update, I can't enter an event in my calendar. I checked iCloud and calendar is activated.

Comment: Be more specific. What have you tried. What are your suggestions, How does it not let you? A screenshot maybe also

Comment: when I go through the normal procedure to add an event to my calendar and I hit done the event does not show up...This function was working fine before my last IOS update

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check would be that you have at least one Calendar selected in prefs…

[image] [image]

Edit your question to add further information if this does not fix your issue.